# Insert with a Select query

Tags: mysql, insert

I've seen this question asked before, but with the select getting all of the vars for the insert, how can I perform an insert with part strings, part select query?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name, surname, foreign_id) 
VALUES ('John', 'Smith', SELECT id FROM foreign_ids WHERE name = 'John')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use insert select  this way

```
INSERT INTO users (first_name, surname, foreign_id)  
SELECT 'John', 'Smith',  id FROM foreign_ids 
WHERE name = 'John';
```

move the literal string you have in value as literal string in corresponding columns in select

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create variable for your **select query**

`$sql = "SELECT id FROM foreign_ids WHERE name = 'John'";
$foreign_id = $conn->query($sql);`

Then put `$foreign_id` inside your **insert query**

`INSERT INTO users (first_name, surname, foreign_id) VALUES ('John', 'Smith', '{$foreign_id}')`